# Get blank page after converting ionic app to RC2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

After following all of the changelog instructions and getting a clean `ionic build` when doing an `ionic serve` I get a blank page.

The browser log does not contain any errors just:

```
Dev server logger closedion-dev.js:113:9
GET http://localhost:8100/build/js/es6-shim.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 16ms]
GET http://localhost:8100/build/js/Reflect.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 15ms]
GET http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 14ms]
GET http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 12ms]
GET http://localhost:8100/build/js/es6-shim.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
GET http://localhost:8100/build/js/Reflect.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
GET http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
GET http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
```

I am trying to track down where the ionic app is failing by putting in some `alert()` calls. I have one at the top of the constructor for my main app but this doesn't get called. How can I track down where it is failing?

My app.module.ts looks likes this:

```js
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VeeUApp } from './app.component';
import { MediaItemData } from '../providers/item-data';
import { UserData } from '../providers/user-data';

import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { ModeratePage } from '../pages/moderate/moderate';
import { FollowPage } from '../pages/follow/follow';
import { SignupPage } from '../pages/signup/signup';
import { TutorialPage } from '../pages/tutorial/tutorial';
import { PhotoPage } from '../pages/photo/photo';
import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { VeeUPage } from '../pages/veeu/veeu';
import { MyItemsPage } from '../pages/my-items/my-items';
import { BookmarksPage } from '../pages/bookmarks/bookmarks';
import { ProfilePage } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import { CheckReportedPage } from '../pages/checkreported/checkreported';

import { Camera } from 'ionic-native';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        VeeUApp,
        LoginPage,
        ModeratePage,
        SignupPage,
        TutorialPage,
        PhotoPage,
        SettingsPage,
        AboutPage,
        VeeUPage,
        MyItemsPage,
        BookmarksPage,
        ProfilePage,
        CheckReportedPage,
        FollowPage
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(VeeUApp, [
            Http,
            UserData,
            MediaItemData
        ])
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        VeeUApp,
        LoginPage,
        ModeratePage,
        SignupPage,
        TutorialPage,
        PhotoPage,
        SettingsPage,
        AboutPage,
        VeeUPage,
        MyItemsPage,
        BookmarksPage,
        ProfilePage,
        CheckReportedPage,
        FollowPage
    ],
    providers: [UserData, MediaItemData, Storage]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Adjust your index.html in src to have rc2 files. Looks your index html looks for beta11 files

Comment: Thanks that was it.

Comment: Write your answer since I can't copy index html from mobile :^)